# Python dataframe replace strings in specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

I have a df looks like this

```
   X
0  100A
1  100B
2  100B
3  500A
4  500B
5  400B
6  700A
7  200B
8  400B
9  900A
10  800B
```

My goal is to change them (string) to integer and divide the number by 10 inside the string if it contains 'A'

```
   X
0  10
1  100
2  100
3  50
4  500
5  400
6  70
7  200
8  400
9  90
10  800
```

I have tried to use for loop for the whole column

```
for i in df.X:
    if 'A' in i:
        y = i.replace('A','') 
        y = int(y)/10
        print(y)
    else:
        k = i.replace('B','')
        k = int(k)
        print(k)
```

But I can only print them out and I dont know how to replace the value directly and store them in the column. Also, this method seems to be slow? Is there a better methods in pandas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a_index = df[df[0].str.endswith('A')]
df = df[0].str.slice(stop=-1).astype(int)
df[a_index.index] = df[a_index.index] / 10
```

First, I save indexes of every row that ends with A. Then, I convert everything to integer. Finally, we divide previously indexed items (`a_index`) by 10

[Demo](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/0b99d22459b65b9de1593a8ba2e4f34df9f76c9f?urlpath=lab%2Ftree%2Fdemo%2FUntitled.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using regular expression:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['100A','100B','200A']})

for row in range(0,len(df)):
    if df.iloc[row].str.contains('A').any():
       new_value = int(re.sub('\D', '', df.iloc[row].values[0]))/10
       df.iloc[row] = new_value
    else:
        new_value = int(re.sub('\D', '', df.iloc[row].values[0]))
        df.iloc[row] = new_value
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
     A
0  10.0
1   100
2  20.0
```